# Rank of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the transformation is from $P_n$ to $P_1$.
$Tf=f(0)+f'(0)x$

My question is how would I find the rank of this transformation.
My thoughts are that it maps to $P_1$ so there can only be $2$ free variables, so the rank would be $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. More formally, if $f\in\mathcal P_n$ then $$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n c_jx^j $$ for some $c_0,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb R$. Since $f(0)=c_0$ and $$f'(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)c_{j+1}x^j, $$ we have $f'(0) = c_1$ and hence $Tf(x) = c_0+c_1x$. It follows that $$T(\mathcal P_n)=\{c_0+c_1x:c_0,c_1 \in\mathbb R\},$$ which is precisely $\mathcal P_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the rank cannot exceed two (why?), now show that it is at least two by showing two two independent elements in the image of the map